# Hyperledger with spring boot, readFromSSL error on channel initialization

Tags: java, spring-boot, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

I'm trying to access my **Hyperledger Fabric** network from a **Spring Boot** application using the **Java SDK**.

Versions :

- OpenJDK 11
- Hyperledger 1.2 (fabric-sdk-java 1.2.0)
- Spring Boot 2.0.5.RELEASE
- Docker 18.06.1-ce

It works fine from a standard Java Spring based application, basically this way (reading crypto materials from local *webapps* folder) :

```
private final static String PATH_CRYPTO_CONFIG = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/webapps/myapp/crypto-config";

private final static String ORG1_PEER0_NAME = "peer0.myorg.ch";
private final static String ORG1_PEER0_ADDRESS = "grpcs://peer0.myorg.ch:7051";
private final static String ORG1_PEER0_CERT = PATH_CRYPTO_CONFIG + "/peerOrganizations/myorg.ch/peers/peer0.myorg.ch/tls/server.crt";

private final static String ORG1_ADMIN_PK = PATH_CRYPTO_CONFIG + "/peerOrganizations/myorg.ch/users/Admin@myorg.ch/msp/keystore/e3f7400bc142ebde34649dee2968757783a6a1ac873c22e5718575cefcdab7e7_sk";
private final static String ORG1_ADMIN_PEM = PATH_CRYPTO_CONFIG + "/peerOrganizations/myorg.ch/users/Admin@myorg.ch/msp/signcerts/Admin@myorg.ch-cert.pem";

private final static String ORDERER_NAME = "orderer.myorg.ch";
private final static String ORDERER_ADDRESS = "grpcs://orderer.myorg.ch:7050";
private final static String ORDERER_CERT = PATH_CRYPTO_CONFIG + "/ordererOrganizations/myorg.ch/orderers/orderer.myorg.ch/tls/server.crt";

public void init() {
    Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());

    HFClient client = HFClient.createNewInstance();

    CryptoSuite cryptoSuite = CryptoSuite.Factory.getCryptoSuite();
    client.setCryptoSuite(cryptoSuite);

    User myOrgAdmin = new AppUser("Admin", ORG1_ADMIN_PK, ORG1_ADMIN_PEM, "MyOrgMSP");
    client.setUserContext(myOrgAdmin);

    Channel ciChannel = client.newChannel("ci-channel");

    Properties ordererProperties = new Properties();
    ordererProperties.setProperty("pemFile", ORDERER_CERT);
    ordererProperties.setProperty("hostnameOverride", ORDERER_NAME);
    ordererProperties.setProperty("sslProvider", "openSSL");
    ordererProperties.setProperty("negotiationType", "TLS");
    ordererProperties.put("grpc.NettyChannelBuilderOption.keepAliveTime", new Object[]{5L, TimeUnit.MINUTES});
    ordererProperties.put("grpc.NettyChannelBuilderOption.keepAliveTimeout", new Object[]{8L, TimeUnit.SECONDS});
    Orderer orderer = client.newOrderer(ORDERER_NAME, ORDERER_ADDRESS, ordererProperties);

    Properties peer0MyOrgProperties = new Properties();
    peer0MyOrgProperties.setProperty("pemFile", ORG1_PEER0_CERT);
    peer0MyOrgProperties.setProperty("hostnameOverride", ORG1_PEER0_NAME + ":7051");
    peer0MyOrgProperties.setProperty("sslProvider", "openSSL");
    peer0MyOrgProperties.setProperty("negotiationType", "TLS");
    peer0MyOrgProperties.put("grpc.NettyChannelBuilderOption.maxInboundMessageSize", 9000000);
    Peer peer0MyOrg = client.newPeer(ORG1_PEER0_NAME, ORG1_PEER0_ADDRESS, peer0MyOrgProperties);

    ciChannel.addOrderer(orderer);
    ciChannel.addPeer(peer0MyOrg, Channel.PeerOptions.createPeerOptions().setPeerRoles(EnumSet.of(Peer.PeerRole.SERVICE_DISCOVERY, Peer.PeerRole.LEDGER_QUERY, Peer.PeerRole.EVENT_SOURCE, Peer.PeerRole.CHAINCODE_QUERY)));

    ciChannel.initialize();
}
```

But I can't make it work when moving to a **Spring Boot** application **packaged as JAR**.

Indeed when dealing with JAR file and embedded Tomcat, I can not specify paths to crypto files. I have to use `ClassPathResource` and I can only get files as streams.

So instead of using `pemFile` to specify the certificates, I use `pemBytes` this way (*crypto-config* folder has been added as resource) :

```
private final static String ORG1_PEER0_NAME = "peer0.myorg.ch";
private final static String ORG1_PEER0_ADDRESS = "grpcs://peer0.myorg.ch:7051";
private final static String ORG1_PEER0_CERT = "peerOrganizations/myorg.ch/peers/peer0.myorg.ch/tls/server.crt";

private final static String ORG1_ADMIN_PK = "peerOrganizations/myorg.ch/users/Admin@myorg.ch/msp/keystore/e3f7400bc142ebde34649dee2968757783a6a1ac873c22e5718575cefcdab7e7_sk";
private final static String ORG1_ADMIN_PEM = "peerOrganizations/myorg.ch/users/Admin@myorg.ch/msp/signcerts/Admin@myorg.ch-cert.pem";

private final static String ORDERER_NAME = "orderer.myorg.ch";
private final static String ORDERER_ADDRESS = "grpcs://orderer.myorg.ch:7050";
private final static String ORDERER_CERT = "ordererOrganizations/myorg.ch/orderers/orderer.myorg.ch/tls/server.crt";

public void init() {
    Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());

    HFClient client = HFClient.createNewInstance();

    CryptoSuite cryptoSuite = CryptoSuite.Factory.getCryptoSuite();
    client.setCryptoSuite(cryptoSuite);

    User myOrgAdmin = new AppUser("Admin", ORG1_ADMIN_PK, ORG1_ADMIN_PEM, "MyOrgMSP");
    client.setUserContext(myOrgAdmin);

    Channel ciChannel = client.newChannel("ci-channel");

    Properties ordererProperties = new Properties();
    ordererProperties.put("pemBytes", FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(new ClassPathResource(ORDERER_CERT).getInputStream()));
    ordererProperties.setProperty("hostnameOverride", ORDERER_NAME);
    ordererProperties.setProperty("sslProvider", "openSSL");
    ordererProperties.setProperty("negotiationType", "TLS");
    ordererProperties.put("grpc.NettyChannelBuilderOption.keepAliveTime", new Object[]{5L, TimeUnit.MINUTES});
    ordererProperties.put("grpc.NettyChannelBuilderOption.keepAliveTimeout", new Object[]{8L, TimeUnit.SECONDS});
    Orderer orderer = client.newOrderer(ORDERER_NAME, ORDERER_ADDRESS, ordererProperties);

    Properties peer0MyOrgProperties = new Properties();
    peer0MyOrgProperties.put("pemBytes", FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(new ClassPathResource(ORG1_PEER0_CERT).getInputStream()));
    peer0MyOrgProperties.setProperty("hostnameOverride", ORG1_PEER0_NAME + ":7051");
    peer0MyOrgProperties.setProperty("sslProvider", "openSSL");
    peer0MyOrgProperties.setProperty("negotiationType", "TLS");
    peer0MyOrgProperties.put("grpc.NettyChannelBuilderOption.maxInboundMessageSize", 9000000);
    Peer peer0MyOrg = client.newPeer(ORG1_PEER0_NAME, ORG1_PEER0_ADDRESS, peer0MyOrgProperties);

    ciChannel.addOrderer(orderer);
    ciChannel.addPeer(peer0MyOrg, Channel.PeerOptions.createPeerOptions().setPeerRoles(EnumSet.of(Peer.PeerRole.SERVICE_DISCOVERY, Peer.PeerRole.LEDGER_QUERY, Peer.PeerRole.EVENT_SOURCE, Peer.PeerRole.CHAINCODE_QUERY)));

    ciChannel.initialize();
}
```

Error is :

```
myapp      | 2018-10-24 10:59:19.318 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel       : Sending proposal to peer0.myorg.ch failed because of: gRPC failure=Status{code=UNKNOWN, description=null, cause=java.lang.AbstractMethodError
myapp      |      at io.netty.internal.tcnative.SSL.readFromSSL(Native Method)
myapp      |      at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.readPlaintextData(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:488)
                  at [...]
myapp      | java.lang.Exception: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNKNOWN
myapp      |      at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.sendProposalToPeers(Channel.java:3619) ~[fabric-sdk-java-1.2.0.jar!/:na]
                  at [...]
myapp      | Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNKNOWN
myapp      |      at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:526) ~[grpc-core-1.13.2.jar!/:1.13.2]
                  at [...]
myapp      | Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null
myapp      |      at io.netty.internal.tcnative.SSL.readFromSSL(Native Method) ~[netty-tcnative-boringssl-static-2.0.10.Final.jar!/:2.0.10.Final]
                  at [...]
myapp      | 2018-10-24 10:59:19.359  WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel       : Channel ci-channel could not load peer CA certificates from any peers.
myapp      | 2018-10-24 10:59:19.367  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.fabric.sdk.ServiceDiscovery          : Channel ci-channel doing discovery with peer: Peer peer0.myorg.ch url: grpcs://peer0.myorg.ch:7051
myapp      | 2018-10-24 10:59:19.823  WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.fabric.sdk.ServiceDiscovery          : Channel ci-channel peer Peer peer0.myorg.ch url: grpcs://peer0.myorg.ch:7051 service discovery error io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNKNOWN
myapp      | 2018-10-24 10:59:20.444  WARN 1 --- [ault-executor-2] o.h.fabric.sdk.PeerEventServiceClient    : Received error on peer eventing service on channel ci-channel, peer peer0.myorg.ch, url grpcs://peer0.myorg.ch:7051, attempts 1. UNKNOWN
```

I have tried :

1. outputing the certificates content and got the expected result
2. creating temporary files from streams and specify paths using `pemFile`
3. downgrading to Java 8
4. adding newer `tcnative` dependency (*netty-tcnative 2.0.18.Final*)

But it still fail with that error.

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it was part of a POC I had to present fairly quickly. Had not too much time to spend on this so I presented the working version without Spring Boot. But for sure if I come back on this and find a solution I'll post it here.